# How to refresh data in a composite field

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, dom, dynamics-crm

When you click on the composite field, a fly-out with individual fields will open for you to start filling in the individual fields. Clicking “Done” button on the fly-out or losing focus of the fly-out will apply the changes and then refresh the composite control value.

[image]

Here's the underlying HTML of the Pop Out:

```
<div class="ms-crm-LinkControl-content ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_flyoutLoadingArea" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block; min-height: 107px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">

    <div id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_flyoutContent" flyoutviewportdomid="tdAreas" flyout-confirming="Mscrm.CompositeDataControlUtilities.checkForComposeAddress" flyout-initialize="Mscrm.CompositeDataControlUtilities.initializeAddressCompositeControl" confirm="Done" flyouttabindex="1240">
<div class="ms-crm-FormSection-Container"><table class="ms-crm-FormSection" id="{8D9B37A4-9191-4AFA-B41A-7C3719764124}" style="table-layout: fixed;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" name="root" valign="top"><colgroup><col width="115"><col><tbody><tr style="display: none;"><td class="ms-crm-Form-Section&#9;ms-crm-Form-Section-Print" colspan="2">   <h3 class="ms-crm-Form"></h3></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the first line of the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">Street 1</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1180" title="111 New Street" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_line1" data-initialized="true" haserror="false">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value" style="display: none;">
            <span>111 New Street<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: block;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="250" attrName="address1_line1" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal" defaultValue="111 New Street"></div><span class="ms-crm-Inline-LockIcon" style="display: none;"><img width="1" height="1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_locked" alt="" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"></span><span title="" class="ms-crm-Inline-WarningIcon" style="display: none;"><img width="1" height="1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_warning" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_warn" alt="Error" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"><div class="ms-crm-Hidden-NoBehavior" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line1_w"></div></span></div></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the second line of the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">Street 2</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1190" title="Select to enter data" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_line2" data-initialized="true">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value ms-crm-Inline-EmptyValue">
            <span>--<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line2_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="250" attrName="address1_line2" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal"></div></div></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the third line of the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">Street 3</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1200" title="Select to enter data" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_line3" data-initialized="true">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value ms-crm-Inline-EmptyValue">
            <span>--<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_line3_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="250" attrName="address1_line3" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal"></div><span class="ms-crm-Inline-LockIcon" style="display: none;"><img width="1" height="1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_locked" alt="" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"></span></div></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the city for the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">City</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1210" title="New Haven" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_city" data-initialized="true">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value">
            <span>New Haven<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_city_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="80" attrName="address1_city" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal" defaultValue="New Haven"></div><span class="ms-crm-Inline-LockIcon" style="display: none;"><img width="1" height="1" class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-inlineedit_locked" alt="" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif"></span></div></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the state or province of the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">State/Province</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1220" title="Select to enter data" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_stateorprovince" data-initialized="true">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value ms-crm-Inline-EmptyValue">
            <span>--<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_stateorprovince_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="50" attrName="address1_stateorprovince" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal"></div></div></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the ZIP Code or postal code for the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">ZIP/Postal Code</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1230" title="06515" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_postalcode" data-initialized="true">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value">
            <span>06515<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_postalcode_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: inactive;" type="text" maxlength="20" attrName="address1_postalcode" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal" defaultValue="06515"></div></div></td></tr><tr height="24"><td title="Type the country or region for the primary address." class="ms-crm-ReadField-Normal ms-crm-FieldLabel-LeftAlign" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country_c"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabel"><span class="ms-crm-InlineEditLabelText" style="text-align: left; max-width: 115px;">Country/Region</span><div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask" style="display: none;">
    </div></span></td><td class="ms-crm-Field-Data-Print" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country_d" data-height="24"><div tabindex="1240" title="Select to enter data" class="ms-crm-Inline-Chrome nvarchar" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country" aria-describedby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country_c" data-layout="0" data-fdeid="PrimaryEntity" data-formid="8448b78f-8f42-454e-8e2a-f8196b0419af" data-attributename="address1_country" data-initialized="true">
        <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Value ms-crm-Inline-EmptyValue">
            <span>--<div class="ms-crm-Inline-GradientMask"></div></span>
        </div>
    <div class="ms-crm-Inline-Edit" style="display: none;"><input title="" class="ms-crm-InlineInput" id="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country_i" aria-labelledby="address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country_c address1_composite_compositionLinkControl_address1_country_w" style="-ms-ime-mode: active;" type="text" maxlength="80" attrName="address1_country" attrPriv="7" controlmode="normal"></div></div></td></tr><tr class="ms-crm-Form-SectionGapRow"><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
</div></div>
```

**When I programmatically update these individual fields (Street1, 2, 3, City, State etc) This does NOT update the composite field (Address Type), unless I click on it and click away from it:**

**Here's a presentation of what happens:**

http://screencast.com/t/con2aNNWY

**How do I force an update on the composite address field?**

Thank you so much for any insight into this matter.

Answer (score 0):

How do you updated the individual fields? After changing the account if click some where else except composite field then it updating or not?

Update : Composite field is updating on change event of account field and it is get affected when you click some where else.

Comment: this is how i update individual fields                         Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_city").setValue(address1_city);
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_country").setValue(address1_country);
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line1").setValue(address1_line1);
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_line2").setValue(address1_line2);
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_stateorprovince").setValue(address1_stateorprovince);

Comment: regarding your update, yes that is correct, so the question is how do i trigger this change?